# Метод с параметром <T>

Tags: c#

Есть необходимость задавать текстовую маску для двух компонентов разных типов. Каждый из них эту возможность поддерживает. Хочу решить это одним методом. Ранее никогда не пользовался, думаю пришло время изучить универсальные методы с . Пишу так:

```
  public static void SetDocNumMask<T>(int id_doctype, ref T ctrl)
        {   
         ctrl.Mask.MaskType = DevExpress.XtraEditors.Mask.MaskType.Simple;
         ctrl.Mask.EditMask = new string('0', 9);
        }
```

Студия ругается на слово Mask

> Severity  Code    Description Project File    Line    Category    Source  Suppression
>   State Error   CS1061  'T' does not contain a definition for 'Mask' and no
>   extension method 'Mask' accepting a first argument of type 'T' could
>   be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Вызываю метод в двух местах

```
Mask.SetDocNumMask<DevExpress.XtraEditors.ComboBoxEdit>(doc_‌​type, ref cbDocNum); 
Mask.SetDocNumMask< DevExpress.XtraEditors.Repository.RepositoryItemTextEdit>(id‌​_doctype, ref repForDocNum);
```

Что я делаю не так?

Comment: для каких компонентов?

Comment: _Что я делаю не так?_ - на данный момент тип `T` может быть любым. Даже тем, у которого нет свойства `Mask`, поэтому компилятор вполне справедливо говорит, что так делать нельзя.

Comment: Вы описываете генерик метод и не указываете никаких ограничений в стиле базового класса или интерфейса. Поэтому студия и ругается так как наиболее общий тип по мнению c# будет object в котором естественно нет Mask

Comment: Mask.SetDocNumMask<DevExpress.XtraEditors.ComboBoxEdit>(doc_type, ref cbDocNum);
Mask.SetDocNumMask< DevExpress.XtraEditors.Repository.RepositoryItemTextEdit>(id_doctype, ref repForDocNum);

Comment: Добавь эти компоненты в вопрос.

Comment: а разве в _ComboBoxEdit_ есть свойство `Mask`?

Comment: есть по идее, судя по информации с девовского сайта "The Mask property is hidden in ComboBoxEdit.Properties"

Comment: @Antykus, судя по их документации - такого свойства у этого контрола нет

Comment: @Grundy есть-есть, я проверил

Answer (score 2):

Считайте, что в вашем случае `T` - это `object`. Никто не дает гарантии, что в `ctrl` будет свойство `Mask`. Для того, чтобы это гарантировать, необходимо указать ограничение - базовый тип или интерфейс, который это свойство содержит:

```
interface IMasked
{
    MaskType Mask { get; }
}

public static void SetDocNumMask<T>(int id_doctype, ref T ctrl)
                        where T: IMasked // <<----
{   
    ctrl.Mask.MaskType = DevExpress.XtraEditors.Mask.MaskType.Simple;
    ctrl.Mask.EditMask = new string('0', 9);
}
```

З.Ы. Если тип может быть прямо вообще-вообще любой и никакого базового типа/интерфейса с `Mask` его не унаследовать, то можно `ctrl` объявить как `dynamic`. Проблемой будет плохая читаемость и отсутствие статической проверки типа компилятором.

Comment: если ctrl объявить как dynamic, то и generic можно убирать, так как в нем уже не будет смысла

Comment: @Grundy Вы правы, я подразумевал dynamic, как колхозную альтернативу дженерикам)

Comment: **"Проблемой будет плохая читаемость и отсутствие статической проверки типа компилятором."* - и про скорость выполнения забывать не надо!

Comment: @free_ze я извиняюсь, туплю, суть я понял. но не могу разобраться, как сделать возможным вызов метода с указанием обоих типов: DevExpress.XtraEditors.Repository.RepositoryItemTextEdit и DevExpress.XtraEditors.ComboBoxEdit

Comment: Ещё можно сделать наследника обоих с указанием интерфейса.

Comment: @Antykus если у них есть общий родитель (базовый класс или интерфейс), декларирующий свойство Mask, то его необходимо указать в ограничении (вместо IMasked в моем примере). Если нет и эти типы нельзя наследовать и сделать обертку (потому что struct, судя по тому, что вы указали ref), то придется убирать дженерики и вместо типа для ctrl указывать dynamic.

Comment: @Antykus всмотрелся в референс. Оба типа - class, поэтому вам не нужен ref. А еще в ComboBoxEdit что-то я не нахожу свойство Mask.

Comment: @free_ze решил вопрос использованием dynamic. В ComboBoxEdit есть Mask, просто зарыто в Properties и видно только в коде

Comment: @Antykus Я бы вам все же посоветовал поискать общий корень, где Mask объявляется или самостоятельно унаследоваться для обоих типов и создать интерфейс вроде IMasked. С dynamic туда можно передавать что угодно и словить ошибку только уже в рантайме.

Comment: @free_ze Да, я понимаю, что по-хорошему это правильный путь, спасибо. Пока опыта мало для этого, оставлю на ближайшее будущее